# It's possible to make a program that shows FPS (frame per second) in Python?

Tags: python, frame-rate

I was wondering...

It's possible to do it?

A simple console command based program that shows how are your FPS, for your currently running game/program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: Beside that it is much simpler to gather statistics when you have hooks inside the measured program, it is possible also to hook on lower level: directly to DirectX or OpenGL. Start your discovery from some [existing](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=359794) [posts](http://nexe.gamedev.net/directKnowledge/). They are in C++ but that's another deal: you can use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html) to interop between Python and C/C++.

As a proof. There is famous [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) applications that does what you say.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Not without knowing the internals of the application, and without the application having the appropriate hooks to perform such a measurement.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the available bindings/hooks to read what that application is doing through whatever library it uses, yes.
Those counters are normally implemented as queries to a program drawing through OpenGL (or directX).

If it's an OGL app, pyOpenGL provides a decent amount of functionality, might be worth your time looking into it. I have no experience with directX, but I assume you might find similar bindings.

http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/frameratedisplayer.htm if you want a simple example to look at that does just that (assuming you're ok puzzling out very little C syntax)